# I need to add "value" of the "select / option" of HTML next to the url that is in the JS. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Tags: javascript, html

Example: 
newurl = url + '& category = 9' + '& difficulty = hard'

The idea is to form a new url, which will be occupied in another function that calls it.

Here I need to write the example and apart I wrote a comment in Spanish and English ... I hope it is understood.
I only need that to finish the code.

**index.html**

```
<form name="formul1" class="cont">       
          <select id="cat" name="cat" onchange="selectCat()">
            <option value="">Any Category</option>
            <option value="&category=9">General Knowledge</option>
            <option value="&category=10">Entertaiment: Books</option>
            <option value="&category=11">Entertaiment: Film</option>
            <option value="&category=12">Entertaiment: Music</option>
            <option value="&category=13">Entertaiment: Musicals & Theatres</option>
            <option value="&category=14">Entertaiment: Television</option>
            <option value="&category=15">Entertaiment: Video Games</option>
            <option value="&category=16">Entertaiment: Board Games</option>
            <option value="&category=17">Science & Nature</option>
            <option value="&category=18">Science: Computers</option>
            <option value="&category=19">Science: Mathematics</option>
            <option value="&category=20">Mythology</option>
            <option value="&category=21">Sports</option>
            <option value="&category=22">Geography</option>
            <option value="&category=23">History</option>
            <option value="&category=24">Politics</option>
            <option value="&category=25">Art</option>
            <option value="&category=26">Celebrities</option>
            <option value="&category=27">Animals</option>
            <option value="&category=28">Vehicles</option>
            <option value="&category=29">Entertaiment: Comics</option>
            <option value="&category=30">Science: Gadgets</option>
            <option value="&category=31">Entertaiment: Japanese Anime & Manga</option>
            <option value="&category=32">Entertaiment: Cartoon & Animations</option>
          </select>
        </form>     
        <h5>Select Difficulty:</h5>
        <form name="formul2" class="cont">          
          <select id="diff" name="diff" onchange="selectDiff()">
            <option value="">Any Difficulty</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=hard">Hard</option>
          </select>
        </form>
```

**game.js**

```
    var btnFetch = document.getElementById('fetch');

  btnFetch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Would fetch newUrl:', newUrl);
    fetch(newUrl)
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(loadedQuestions => {
    console.log(loadedQuestions.results);
    questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
      const formattedQuestion = {
        question: loadedQuestion.question
      };

      const answerChoices = [...loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers];
      formattedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      answerChoices.splice(
        formattedQuestion.answer - 1,
        0,
        loadedQuestion.correct_answer
      );

      answerChoices.forEach((choice, index) => {
        formattedQuestion["choice" + (index + 1)] = choice;
      });

      return formattedQuestion;
    });

    startGame();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't use two `<form>`, then you shouldn't use redundant values in your `<option>`, e.g. you should use something like `value="32"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an object to hold the values, update its values `onchange` and then `join()` them - and pass this **newUrl** to the fetch function.

```js
// var url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20';
//SELECT CATEGORY
//CATEGORY => 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 32

const obj = {
  url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20',
  difficulty: '',
  category: ''
}
let newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('')

function selectCat() {
  var c = document.getElementById("cat").value;
  console.log(c);
  obj.category = c
  newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('')
  // return c;
}

//SELECT DIFFICULTY
//DIFFICULTY => any, easy, medium, hard
function selectDiff() {
  var d = document.getElementById("diff").value;
  console.log(d);
  obj.difficulty = d
  newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('')
  // return d;
}

/*ANIDAR VALUE DE CATTEGORY Y DIFFICULTY 
  JUNTO A LA URL PARA OBTENER LA NEWURL 

  NEST VALUE TO CATEGORY AND DIFFICULTY
  NEXT TO THE URL TO GET THE NEWURL*/

// click event on button
const btnFetch = document.getElementById('fetch')

btnFetch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Would fetch newUrl:', newUrl)
  // fetch(newUrl).then(res => {})
})
```

```html
<button id="fetch">FETCH URL</button><br /><br />

<form name="formul1" class="cont">
  <select id="cat" name="cat" onchange="selectCat()">
    <option value="">Any Category</option>
    <option value="&category=9">General Knowledge</option>
    <option value="&category=10">Entertaiment: Books</option>
    <optiseon value="&category=11">Entertaiment: Film</option>
      <option value="&category=12">Entertaiment: Music</option>
      <option value="&category=13">Entertaiment: Musicals & Theatres</option>
      <option value="&category=14">Entertaiment: Television</option>
      <option value="&category=15">Entertaiment: Video Games</option>
      <option value="&category=16">Entertaiment: Board Games</option>
      <option value="&category=17">Science & Nature</option>
      <option value="&category=18">Science: Computers</option>
      <option value="&category=19">Science: Mathematics</option>
      <option value="&category=20">Mythology</option>
      <option value="&category=21">Sports</option>
      <option value="&category=22">Geography</option>
      <option value="&category=23">History</option>
      <option value="&category=24">Politics</option>
      <option value="&category=25">Art</option>
      <option value="&category=26">Celebrities</option>
      <option value="&category=27">Animals</option>
      <option value="&category=28">Vehicles</option>
      <option value="&category=29">Entertaiment: Comics</option>
      <option value="&category=30">Science: Gadgets</option>
      <option value="&category=31">Entertaiment: Japanese Anime & Manga</option>
      <option value="&category=32">Entertaiment: Cartoon & Animations</option>
  </select>
</form>
<h5>Select Difficulty:</h5>
<form name="formul2" class="cont">
  <select id="diff" name="diff" onchange="selectDiff()">
    <option value="">Any Difficulty</option>
    <option value="&difficulty=easy">Easy</option>
    <option value="&difficulty=medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="&difficulty=hard">Hard</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null 
:(

Comment: ??? What's the context? You need to have an element with an id, and add the click event listener to that. In my snippet I added a button, and added the event listener.

Comment: I wrote everything the same as you... I don't understand

Comment: The snippet works, as intended. The error you commented points to the direction that the item does not exist, when the `addEventListener` is run. Something may be missing in your code, or the order is not the same. Or, it may be that you put the JS BEFORE the actual HTML - usually JS comes at the end (after HTML). If you need to put it in the `<head>` (or just before the HTML), then you have to ensure that this code is run after the HTML is loaded - like with `jQuery(document).ready()`

Comment: Or you can split the snippet code into two parts - first part is the URL, the select, etc. and you put the `addEventListener` and the `document.getElementById()` in a separate script tag at the end. Doesn't matter - the only thing that happens is that you won't be able to start fetching until your page is loaded.

Comment: The third option is to put the function on the button's `onclick` handler (like with the selects' `onchange` - but that way you have to make sure that it can get the URL that is created. This way you can get rid of the `document.getElementById()` and the `addEventListener()` stuff.

Comment: That's great! :) What was the problem?

Comment: JS was before HTML

Comment: Yeah, that explains :) THX

Comment: Now I have the error again, but now it is in directing to the next html (game.html) ...TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I think you should add all your code for everyone to see all the information. Or you can create a code snippet (jsfiddle, codepen, etc - whichever you like), and see whether it works there. If not you can link it in your question.

Comment: The problem is from index.html to game.html

Comment: So you want to pass the choices from one page to the other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202433/discussion-between-muka-gergely-and-luis-fernando-silva).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here’s what you are expecting the user to do.

1. Select a category from drop down
2. Select difficulty from dropdown
3. Create a well formed URL from these values to fetch some date.

From your code it is not clear when `fetch` gets called.

My recommendation would be to:

1. Create one main form at the parent and include the two drop downs as child inputs.
2. Once the user selects the value on dropdown you need not do anything immediately.
3. On submit of form (you should add a submit button), call a JavaScript action.( using `onsubmit` event of form like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp.
4. The first argument of this JS function is an `event` which will have the values of the dropdown selected by the user inside of the form node which can be accessed using form name.
5. Construct the new URL using the values and call fetch.